# Unknown whitespace character displaying in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word

Can anyone tell me what is the name of the whitespace character preceding the letter "a" in the image?  It looks a bit like a tilde (~) with one or two pixels directly below.  The blue "dot" following the number "3" can be duplicated by pressing the space bar.  I hope that if I know its name I can understand any behavioral peculiarities.

[image: Screenshot of text within Microsoft Word for MAC 15.33]

The font is "Georgia".  But I tried other fonts and this character does not change.  I got this when I copied text from a Wordpress blog and pasted into this version of Word.  This character almost always appeared after a full stop ("period" or "."). Typically in my writing, I enter 2 spaces after a full stop.  When I copied this data from WordPress in the Google Chrome browser and then pasted it into Microsoft Word the second space was always converted to this character.  This character also appeared elsewhere in the Word doc, though not in any pattern I could discern.

I tried pasting the WordPress data into ViM on Mac but this character did not appear in ViM.

Answer (score 0):

This symbol is a non-breaking space in Microsoft Word on Mac. Enter a non-breaking space using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.